# Copyright issue: Webview of a popular site within an app

Tags: android

Can embedding a mobile version of a site within an app cause legel issues.. People have varying opinions on this, it seems very common.

Comment: Do **you** have the permission to embed it? If the answer is no! Don't! :)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, as you can tell by reading [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). This is not a programming question, and StackOverflow is not a law office. Please consult with qualified legal counsel for questions like this.

Comment: At t0mm13b lol why :P I DONT Lol

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how much programming information do you get from lawyers?

Comment: According to [Google Play Developer Program Policies](http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html), you may not "[p]rovide a webview of a website not owned or administered by you (unless you have permission from the website owner/administrator to do so)".

Answer (score 2):

I would seek the permission of the website owner, whether or not I am legally required to have permission, it's just good manors and save yourself legal troubles.